# Fetch tweets using Twitter4J in Spring

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, twitter4j

I'm interested in use [`Twitter4J`](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) to fetch tweets from Twitter streaming API. This library would be used from a Spring class annotated with @Service and would received updates in a [`StatusListener`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/StatusListener.html) to store it in a DB later. My question is, would I stop other actions while receiving updates or users would be able to interact with the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users should still be able to use the website.  You could do the twitter4j parsing in a bean with scope marked as prototype so it wouldn't be a singleton and therefore wouldn't create any threading issues with other users logged into the system if it was marked as @Service.

Remember, Spring beans are singletons by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you give me a little example about the prototype part? I'm not familiarized with that.

Comment: It just means the bean isn't created as a singleton.  So say 3 users login and you've made a class level variable you don't get multithread issues.  Of course, if your bean isn't using a class level variable it doesn't make a difference to you.  Take a look at http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-scopes-examples/

Comment: I'm going to use Scope annotation, but my question is, do I need two classes, the fetcher and a class to parse each tweet and save it to my DB? If this is the case and I use Autowired in the fetcher, the parse class would be a singleton or would be still a prototype?

Comment: You could do it both with singletons if you wanted to.  Make a DAO that persists the tweet and a Service that does the web service calls.

Comment: Yeah, of course, I have a repository to persist the tweets. I'm talking about the class to parse and persist tweets. This class would have an Autowired repo but I'm not sure if I set a prototype scope and I use Autowired in my fetcher to use this parser if a new instace would be used for each tweet or would be singleton also.

Comment: It would create a new object if it's of type prototype but it wouldn't if you just don't set a scope.  Bare in mind the potential performance hit of creating a new object each time with a prototype bean, although you'd expect it to be minimal.